# Is $k+p$ prime infinitely many times?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have the following conjecture:

> Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be even. Now $k+p$ is prime for infinitely many primes $p$.

I couldn't find anything on this topic, but I'm sure this has been thought of before. I tried to solve this using [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) and the [Green–Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem), but no luck with those. Is this question equivalent to an existing open problem? If not, how can I prove this (I prefer hints, but I appreciate full answers, too)?

---

**- Edit -**

As has been pointed out in the comments, this is *not* a duplicate. I'm asking for infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+k$ is prime, not only one.

Comment: Note that this is false for $k$ odd.

Comment: Yes, I thank both of you. I edited the question.

Comment: For $k=2$ this is equivalent to the twin prime conjecture....

Comment: @Micah That question doesn't involve the condition that it be expressible in infinitely many ways.

Comment: Wait, never mind, the "infinitely many" makes it different than that.

Comment: To be fair that is not a duplicate: this question asks for a much more general problem "can every even integer be expressed as the difference of two primes **in infinitely many ways**". Anyway, it should be clear by now that this question is an unsolved problem (and a Very Hard$^{\text{TM}}$ one).

Comment: If it's an extremely hard problem to answer just existence, then it's probably even harder to prove that there are infinitely many.

Comment: @T.Bongers Possibly, but it could have been the case that this conjecture was known to be false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Polignac's conjecture.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) It also implies the [twin prime conjecture.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) Therefore your conjecture is intermediate in strength between those two.

Comment: Well, I don't require $p$ and $k+p$ to be consecutive primes, so it's not the same. The Plignac's conjecture states that there are infinitely many prime gaps size $k$, I just want the difference of the primes to be $k$, but I don't care whether or not there are primes between $p$ and $k+p$

Comment: You're correct. I've edited my answer.

Comment: There is another related open problem that has been studied, see [here](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/conjectures/) ("Every even number is the difference of two primes.").  I don't think it has a proper name.  OP's conjecture is even stronger than that since we are asking for infinitely many for each difference, not just a single one.

Answer (score 2):

There are some results known. It has been proven that there is at least one $k \leq 246$ that appears infinitely often as a prime gap.

Furthermore, assuming respectively the Elliott–Halberstam conjecture and its generalisation, one can prove that there is at respectively at least one $k \leq 12$ and $k \leq 6$ that appears infinitely often as a prime gap.

Of course, a prime gap is stronger than your condition, since the primes don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: The distinction between "prime gap" and "primes with difference $k$" is immaterial in this "$\le 246$" formulation.  In fact I believe the sieve methods used here just establish "there are infinitely many blocks of width 246 containing at least two primes".  The equivalence to "some prime gap $\le 246$" is easy.

Comment: For a reference, the result that an even $k$ exists is ___Yitang Zhang's theorem___. He proved in 2013 that such a $k$ exists and can be chosen to be at most $70{,}000{,}000$. Before 2013 it was not known if $p_{n+1}-p_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.